# Moving apps to SD card?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, app2sd

How do I exactly move apps to the SD Card? I have already rooted my phone, but I still don't know what to do next. I did some research, but I ended up getting stuff like "Settings > Apps > [App] > Move to SD Card" but that button is nowhere to be found...

Comment: I forgot to ask.what device is your?which OS version are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good job rooting! Makes the process easier to explain. 
First of all, take your SD card and backup all the data.
Then, partition it into two partitions - 1 half for regular usage. Format this as FAT. 2nd Half for the apps. Format this EXT2 format. I'm not too sure how to format on windows. I use the mac disk utility.
Then, insert the SD card back in and download Link2SD or Apps2SD. Load up the SD card. Link2SD will ask you to choose the partition for the apps. Here choose the EXT2 option. Once you've selected it (and rebooted your phone, which is required to load up the partition), you can link apps to SD card. Linking is just like moving and saves a lot of internal space.

Feel free to comment if you have any Qs.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Will report back once I try it out.

Comment: Okay, so I've created a second partition for my SD Card. I choose the EXT2 format for it. It all went fine for the partitioning part. I then downloaded Link2SD. But when I opened Link2SD, it prompted me to select the file system of my SD Card's second partition. I selected the EXT2 option and pressed "Ok". Then I got "Mount Script cannot be created. mount: No such device" Help please?

Comment: I forgot to ask, what device is yours? Which OS  version are you running? There's this app called busybox installer on the play store. Download that and install busybox, if you already haven't. You need that.

Comment: My device is a Lenovo A328 with an Android 4.4.2

Comment: What do I do once I install it?

Comment: Well, after you install busybox, and load up Link2SD , you should be able to mount the SD card partition. Have you tried with EXT2 again? If that still doesn't work, try other options.
If that still doesn't work, give Apps2SD a shot. It's actually better

Comment: I tried Apps2SD, it worked like a charm :D Thanks dude!

Comment: Glad to help :D